# CSS -moz-linear-gradient

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I was trying to understand some syntax of `-moz-linear-gradient`, This is what i am trying to understand: `-moz-linear-gradient(0% 0% 270deg,#FEFEFE, #f0f0f0);`,
I was looking [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient), and [Here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient), But i did not find the syntax as above the syntax is from: [This pagination style(with gradient)](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-pagination-styles), I did understand the deg, and the colors but what is the `0% 0%` doing?, If anyone can explain i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: this link can be helpful http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this [link](http://help.codeschool.com/discussions/html-5/157-level-5-challenge-8):

*Since the `-moz-linear-gradient(19% 75% 90deg, #FA8246, #BB5422)` syntax is only for Firefox 3.5 (**i am not sure about this**) and older, we think it makes sense to teach the newer (and simpler) `-moz-linear-gradient(top, #FA8246, #BB5422)` syntax instead.*

Anyway, you should adopt what is in the documentation now.

Something like this works, like replacing the position (left, right):

```
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(50% 0deg, white, #BB5422)
```

that is equal to:

```
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg 50%, white, #BB5422)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YjfSB/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer loops, But do you know just for solving this syntax what will change if i play with the values of 0% and 0%, Thanks again.

Comment: @uBlankText, i think the only thing affected is the start position. Where is % you can use fixed values like 300px.